# Variable parameter count in laravel route

Tags: php, routes, laravel

I'm trying to create a route with a required parameter and then an n amount of parameters. The n amount is not known, only that it is more then zero.

```
<?php
Route::get('{tree_slug}/{n-amount}', 'DecisionTreeController@branch');
?>
```

This would need to match:
some-slug/a/b/c and some-slug/d/e or some-slug/a/b/c/d/e

And then preferably an array as second argument in the controller function, like so:

```
<?php // assume controller context here
public function branch($tree_slug, $choices = array())
```

I know how to do such things in Symfony, but is it possible in Laravel? And how?

Comment: I haven't used Symfony, but Laravel uses the same routing. So give it a go to how you'd do it in Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach:

```
// routes.php

Route::get('{tree_slug}/{choices?}', 'DecisionTreeController@branch')->where('choices', '(.*)');
```

Your controller:

```
<?php

class DecisionTreeController extends BaseController {

    public function branch($tree_slug, $choices)
    {
        $choices = explode('/', $choices);
        print_r($choices);
    }

}
```

However, you have to be careful. Be sure to place this route at the end of your `routes.php` file, because Laravel will check your rules in the order that you defined them, and this pattern will match any given URL. So, in order to allow other routes to be executed, they should be **before** this one.